# How do I find my SVN source?

Tags: svn

I currently have an svn respository checked out to my local machine. How do I find the source URL that my changes are being checked into? (The URL of the actual repository).

Running Linux Ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`svn info` should print the URL.

See [svn info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re13.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try `svn info` in your working directory and scan the output for `URL:` and/or `Repository Root:`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a file called `entries` inside the `.svn` folder which exists in your checked-out project's every directory. You can check inside of that and get your URL, username, and sometimes your password.